# Prove a distance is a metric space

Tags: calculus, metric-spaces

This is easy proof but i can't understand.
Let $X=\Bbb R^n$ and $d(x,y)=\max_{i\in\{1,n\}}|x_i-y_i|$ 
i) $d(x,y)\ge0$ and ii) $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ are easy.
But iii) is $d(x,y)+d(y,z) \ge d(x,z)$ is so hard.
$d(x,y)+d(y,z) \ge d(x,z)$ 
<=> $\max_{i\in\{1,n\}}|x_i-y_i|+\max_{i\in\{1,n\}}|y_i-z_i| \ge \max_{i\in\{1,n\}}|x_i-z_i|$
We choose $j \in \{1,n\}$ so that $|x_j-y_j|$ is max, but we not sure $|y_j-z_j|$ and $|x_j-z_j|$ max too. 
Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider 3 vector $x,y,z$. $d(x,z)$ assumes its value at some $i_0 \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ so that $d(x,z)=|x_{i_0}- z_{i_0}|$.

It's clear that $|x_{i_0}- z_{i_0}| \le |x_{i_0}- y_{i_0}| + |y_{i_0}- z_{i_0}|$ by the usual triangle inequality for $\Bbb R$ and also $|x_{i_0}- y_{i_0}|\le d(x,y)$ (a value at some index is $\le$ than the maximum over all coordinates) and also $|y_{i_0}- z_{i_0}| \le d(y,z)$.

So $$d(x,z)=|x_{i_0}- z_{i_0}| \le d(x,y) + d(y,z)$$

as required.